# How to extract contour lines from bathymetry profiles (mainly cross sections)

Tags: qgis, contour, bathymetry, rivers, cross-section

I need to extract contour lines from surveyed bathymetry profiles.
The profiles are .csv files with multiple points and X, Y and Z coordinates. There are cross sections and a single longitudinal section:
[image]

**Is it possible to "connect" the profiles with contour lines each 5m, ideally in Qgis ?**

Things I tried:

- Creating a DEM from the profiles with TIN interpolation tool, then extracting the contour lines. This doesn't work too weel and creates strange shapes in some places. Also I don't want to interpolate unknown values, simply to "link" existing ones.
  [image]
- IDW Interpolation also creates values in between profiles, not what I am looking for.
- The Concave hull tool is closer to my goal but creates flat shapes.

This is what I am thinking about, but don't know how to get:
[image]

The structure of the data looks like this one:
https://we.tl/t-AzmKZBMSe6

Comment: Are the measurements on each cross-section exact 5m multiples or do you first need to interpolate on those to get 5m interval depth locations? Any chance you can make sample data available? How many of these do you have? Does the data have any other structure, like knowing the order along the lake or the direction of the cross section across the lake?

Comment: The points on the cross-sections are not evenly distributed, but about 20-30cm from each other on a straight line. In some parts there is a couple meters gap, as some bad soundings were deleted. The data is simply XYZ files, and cross-sections are not evely spaces from one another

Comment: I was asking more about the depth values, to see if the 5m depth increments were identifiable as input points, or if step 1 might be to gather each cross-section and then interpolate in 1 dimension to get the 5m depth locations on each cross-section. That looks difficult since the XYZ data has no information on which cross-section for each data point.

Comment: Oh I see, no the measurments don't have fixed increments. Each profile if in a different so I know which section is which. I will try to interpolate the cross-sections, then "select and link" the points with the same altitude.